# Json object pass as param in dynamicallay created element click event using javascript/angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

Json object pass as param in dynamicallay created element click event using `javascript/angularjs`

```
var _dataObj = "{"sor_SourcingAgentId":1,"sor_Name":"xx"}"

var _dynHtml=  '<input type="button"  ng-click="fnSelectcustomer(\'' + _dataObj + '\',\'' + data['sor_Name'].toString() + '\',\'' + data['sor_SourcingAgentId'].toString() + '\')" value="select"/>';
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Pass id or class to your button and try it using `on('click')`

Comment: but its inside angularjs datatable column click event that is the problem

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle or plnkr or add your js code here.

Comment: Can you explain the problem in detail?

Answer (score 0):

If click event is not working in your code then use this

`var _dynHtml=  '<input type="button"  ng-click="fnSelectcustomer(\'' + _dataObj + '\',\'' + data['sor_Name'].toString() + '\',\'' + data['sor_SourcingAgentId'].toString() + '\')" value="select"/>';`

add below code in your controller

`$compile(_dynHtml)($scope);`

It will call your function. I guess this is what your looking for

Comment: My pleasure glad  to help you